# How to change values in an array using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Just two questions in regards to this code.

1. How do I iterate through the array and actually change the values in the array.
2. Why does the foreach keep giving me an out of bounds exception. It works fine for the usual for loop (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++), but I havn't used this foreach before?

```
package experimental;

import java.sql.Array;

public class foreachExp {

    public int[] anArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,};

    public void foreachArray() {
        for (int i : anArray) {
            anArray[i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @IrishGeek82:  The comma has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for-each does not work based on array index but implements an iterative solution, the int `i` variable will be representative of a single element of data from your supplied array. So in the loop, you effectively call:

```
anArray[1] = 1 + 1;
anArray[2] = 2 + 1;
anArray[3] = 3 + 1;
anArray[4] = 4 + 1;
anArray[5] = 5 + 1;
```

As you can see, `anArray[5]` would be out of bounds, as the length of the array is only 5 long (0-4)

If you want to change the values, you do not use a for-each loop (could hackily do it using a `Box` of some sort, but with an array it would be silly to).

So with an array, this would be the advisable solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    anArray[i]++;
}
```

As you have already mentioned

Comment: Ok so the enhanced for loop is simply for getting information from values but not for changing them?

Comment: In most situations, yes. There are certainly applications where you can change values in a data structure using this (especially with Objects), but when just working with Arrays and primitives, you would want the "vanilla" `for`.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
for (int i : anArray) {
```

`i` refers to the value itself, not the index. So asking for `array[5]` gives you an out of bounds exception (valid indices are 0 to 4).

You can instead use a normal for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<anArray.length; ++i) {
    anArray[i]++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental difference between a `for` loop and an enhanced-for loop is that the enhanced-for loop actually binds the values of the array to the variable itself.

So, your enhanced-for is pulling this on each iteration:

- i = 1
- i = 2
- i = 3
- i = 4
- i = 5 // this is the size of your array

Enhanced for loops aren't meant for changing values.  You would use a normal `for` loop for that.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid response to the question.  It may not have been the first, but it's perfectly valid.  Dunno who downvoted me and why.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I upvoted you to get rid of it if that helps?

Comment: Well, it's not like I'm wounded or anything.